# whats the best set-up for locations of front-end and back-end mdb files?

Tags: ms-access

I have two mdb access files, one of them is front-end app and the other one is back-end.
They both resides in the same pc. My question is if I move out the front-end out of this location and copy it in client pcs for each pc connecting to the back-end db, how can it affect the bloating in the front-end and even the back-end mdb files?
My guess is that the bloating rate in the front-end should now be distributed over the client pcs' front-end files. But I am not sure if it can impact the back-end too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back end needs to be somewhere everyone can access it. Front ends should be distributed to all users so as there aren't any read/write conflicts or corruption from multiple users using the same front end. This is the preferred method of distributing FE/BE Access systems.

How can it affect bloating? Well, for one, you'll have X more users inserting/updating/deleting data out of your database. So instead of your 20 records, it could become 1000 records because the Back End is now supporting multiple users. This is normal database file size increase.

### Bloating

---

What causes it?

- Temporary tables
- Non-querydef SQL statements
- Not closing Recordsets/QueryDef objects (Close them and set them `= Nothing`)
- Images
- Forms
- Row Locking

(I'm sure there are other things.)

I believe over the years JET has tried to push some updates to stifle some of the issues surrounding what causes bloating, but it does still occur.

If your users will just be using forms/reports/etc.. I think you will be fine with C&R if the size becomes worrisome.

Here's Microsoft's [attempt](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/303528) at explaining how to keep your Access DB working 'smoothly.' There's also decompiling/recompiling if you're experiencing some VBA errors or 'Out Of Memory' occurs.